# I'm trying to run my node project on my vs code terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, command-line-interface

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\desktop\dev-folder\node\node.js'
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.10.0
PS C:\Users\user\desktop\dev-folder\node> node node -v
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\desktop\dev-folder\node\node'
←[90m    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Then i get this error,But if i run it on my CLi it works perfectly

i tried running it on my CLi it worked perfectly but when i run it on
vs code integrated terminal it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

is exactly path `C:\Users\user\desktop\dev-folder\node\node`?

You can get path of file in vscode:

1. Right click in file js need to run
2. Click `Copy Path`
3. In vscode terminal, run `node {path_copied}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

1. go to the folder path in vs terminal
2. run node <filename.js>